# Search for class by userID then display the class in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html

First if you give examples, can you do it in aspx engine. I am most familiar with that. If not, I guess it doesn't matter, I will try to figure the razor engine example out.

This is an upgrade from my last question with the progress I made.

I am trying to create a search box that takes in user id then displays the class associated with the user input then display it in a table. If it does not have it, a message below the search button should display No Class found. This is what I have so far. I have a lot of red underline in my examples. I don't know where Im messing up at.

**html**

```
     <div align="center">
        <form id="searchUser" method="post" action="what do I put here?">
            <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                Enter ID:
             </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="<%(string)(ViewBag.userid)%>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="searchButton" id="searchButton">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </form>
   </div>
   <hr /> 

   <%if(ViewBag.searchClass !=null)
     { %>
     <h2>Search Resuls</h2>
     <br />
     <%AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass searchClassList= ViewBag.searchClass;%>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                UserID:
            </th>
            <th>
                Email:
            </th>
            <th>
            Last Four Digits:
            </th>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <%=searchClassList.userId%>
            </td>
            <td class="content">
             <%=searchClassList.email%>
            </td>
              <td class="content">
              <%=searchClassList.lastFourdigits%>
             </td>
           </tr>
           <%} %>
     </table>
      <% else %>
    <% { %>
        <h2>No Class found.</h2>
    <% } %>
```

**Controller**  this is where i made my instance of a class for the search button to find

```
 public ActionResult Search()
    {
        string userId = Request["UserId"];

        bool view = false;

        if (Request["UserId"] == null)
        {
            view = true;
        }
        if (!view)
        {

            AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass searchClass = new Models.SearchClass();
            {
                searchClass.lastFourdigits = "2222";
                searchClass.userId = "12345";
                searchClass.email = "diaz@gmail.com";

                string lastFourdigits = searchClass.lastFourdigits;
                string userIdd = searchClass.userId;
                string email = searchClass.email;

                ViewBag.searchClass = searchClass;
                ViewBag.lastFourdigits = lastFourdigits;
                ViewBag.userId = userIdd;
                ViewBag.email = email;
            }
        }
        return View();
```

**Model**

```
    namespace AAlexUsers.Models
{
    public class SearchClass
    {
            public string userId { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string lastFourdigits { get; set; }

            public SearchClass()
            {
                userId = "";
                email = "";
                lastFourdigits = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: action="what do I put here?" should be action="Search"

Comment: my if statement have a red line underneath it..do you know why this is happening. can you check my syntax?

Comment: what is the exact exception/error?

Comment: are you using webforms (aspx) view engine or razor here?

Comment: I am using webform aspx engine

Comment: @prashanth do you know where my syntax or escape brackets misplaced for the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got one error when I ran your code in VS2010 (MVC3).

The `</table>` should be before `<%} %>`

You can find a lot of good info about razor compared to webforms engine [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx).